# Calculate average and mean based on two column data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
df
Speed   Zone
1.33    Zone 1
0.37    Zone 1
0.52    Zone 1
1.17    Zone 1
8.36    Zone 2
4.46    Zone 2
2.16    Zone 2
4.45    Zone 2
5.50    Zone 3
5.29    Zone 3
3.49    Zone 3
1.11    Zone 3
0.89    Zone 4
2.16    Zone 5
0.83    Zone 5
1.17    Zone 5
```

I calculate `average` or `mean` of the speed every zone by using this code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("speed_zone.csv")
df = df[df.Zone == 'Zone 1']
df["Speed"].mean()
```

However, I have to copy and do it again into a new cell. I have many zones to do. I am a beginner in python, how to calculate `mean` or `average` of the speed column and make a table automatically simultaneous. 
My expected result looks like this:

```
Mean_Speed  Zone 
0.8475      Zone 1
4.8575      Zone 2
3.8474      Zone 3
```

Comment: Use `df.groupby("Zone").mean()`

Comment: thank you for your answer. if they're more than one column such speed or etc, will calculate the mean?

Comment: yop, it return mean of all numeric columns

Comment: is it possible if only speed column I just want to calculate the `mean`?

Comment: `df.groupby("Zone")['speed'].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df.groupby("Zone").agg("mean")
```

You might also want to look at the [documentation of agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).
You can specify different aggregations for each variable